# How to open new tab with Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm developing an app using Angular js and i'm doing a a questionnaire component which has a lot of nested pages to develop, so instead of doing changes and then spends a lot of time to return to the same page and see the results - i was advised to use Puppeteer to simulate to automate to page navigation ... I've found many examples of Puppeteer that outputs a png file - but none that's simply open a URL...

Here is what i've tried so far...

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://cnn.com');
 // await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  //await browser.close();

})();
```

As you can see in my example - it didn't opened a new page...

Comment: You opened a new page with browser.newPage(). Try launching puppeteer with headless set to false to see it in action

Comment: @voiys Thanks! it did the trick